# Take the number, date and time; search from top for number, which equal or more; show info from 2 rows located left from founded number

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have number 4679,286 in column **I**, date 09.10.2017 in column **H**, and time 15:00 in column **G**.

Column **E** contains numbers, **D** and **C** – date and time, where we will search for.

---

We need to search from 15:00 09.10.2017, for number, which equal or more than 4679,286. From-top-to-bottom way.

---

The right answer will be `4715,30` on sample *(check screenshot or link)*.

> After we found this number, we need to fill 2 cells from left, with
>   the date and time from the row of founded number.

---

[image: Sample Screenshot]

- Google Sheets sample:
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AD5tJr2G83SaxGTy1N02Xk67623heXOiFE4pTCRdKs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(E:E; C:C>=G2; D:D>=H2; E:E>=I2); 2; 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, it works! Is it possible to make last point of the goal? – Show result as time and date of founded row, in 2 cells, instead of founded price?

Comment: Formula got a bug: if G2 > time of result, it shows that G2 = time of result. 

For example time 15:00 10.10.2017 and object of search at 07:00 12.10.2017, so it still shows 15:00 12.10.2017. But if search time are 06:00 12.10.2017, it shows me correct result at 07:00 12.10.2017.

Comment: try: `=INDEX(filter(C:D; C:C>G2; D:D>=H2; E:E>=I2); 2)`

Comment: Solution was to delete "C:C>G2;" completely from formula. Now solved.